# How to search all the user accounts in a domain in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, winapi

How do I search all the user accounts in a domain in .NET?

Not the computer names in the domain, but the user accounts, that's what you are using to log on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine,Environment.MachineName);
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
user.Name = "*";
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
ps.QueryFilter = user;
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = ps.FindAll();
foreach (Principal p in result)
{
    using (UserPrincipal up = (UserPrincipal)p)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(up.Name);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
            foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username : {0}", envVar["Name"]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

See also *[How to list all Windows Users](http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/how-to-list-all-windows-users/)*.

Comment: Does the second one work for a domain or only for local users?

Comment: for users that are specifically on th machine you right local users

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
List<string> LdapUsers = new List<string>();

if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain))
{
    string username = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    domain = username.Substring(0, username.IndexOf("\\"));
}

PrincipalContext context;
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain))
    context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, user, password);
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain))
    context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
else
    context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal userP = new UserPrincipal(context);
userP.Enabled = true;
PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher();
pS.QueryFilter = userP;

PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> result = pS.FindAll();
foreach (Principal p in result)
    LdapUsers.Add(domain + "\\" + p.SamAccountName);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to search for domain users:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

        using (var domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain())
        using (var directoryEntry = domain.GetDirectoryEntry())
        using (var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry, "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"))
        {
            directorySearcher.PageSize = 1000;

            using (var searchResults = directorySearcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResults)
                {
                    using (var userEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(userEntry.Properties["cn"][0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```